# Can optimization version problem whose decision version is NP-complete be solved in poly-time iff P=NP?

Tags: optimization, computer-science, computational-complexity, computability, np-complete

I have proved the decision version of my problem be $\mathcal{NP}$-complete. And I know that if I can solve the optimization version in poly-time, then I can just to compare the obtained minimum (or maximum) with target value in decision version. Thus, the decision version can be solved in poly-time as well. Since the decision version is $\mathcal{NP}$-hard, so is the optimization version, i.e., the optimization version is $\mathcal{NP}$-hard.

My question is how to prove the converse direction: if the decision version can be solved in poly-time, can the optimization version be solved in poly-time as well?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/111344/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3278331/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 2):

You can make a polynomial number of calls to your solver for the NP-complete problem to find the optimal solution.  E.g., for the travelling salesman problem you would perform a binary search with a series of queries asking whether there is a tour with some cost $c$, gradually adjusting $c$ and bracketing the solution space until you have the optimal solution.

Comment: Just knowing what the _cost_ of the optimal solution is, doesn't necessarily tell you what that solution is. There are many optimization problems where you can also reconstruct the optimal _solution_ bit for bit by asking a series of slightly varying questions, though.

Comment: As far as I know, all NP-complete problems are downward self-reducible so you should be able to extract the solution once you know that it exists, again with another polynomially bounded series of calls to the solver.

Comment: x @Kyle: Hmm you're right. If all else fails you can reduce to SAT and extract a certificate bit by bit. At least if we consider it implicit in the term "optimization problem" that it's as easy to check a solution as to find it, the solution itself can be that certificate.